# Can a single CloudWatch alarm send alerts for any set of dimensions?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I'm hoping to use a custom CloudWatch metric to track occurrences of auth failures in calls to my API. I want these custom metrics to use dimensions in order to partition the metric by caller so that I can take per-client-specific actions when the metric passes the alarm threshhold (in my case sending Slack alerts to client-specific channels they have set up with us). However, it's not clear from the AWS documentation if you can set up a general purpose alarm for a metric and receive alerts *for all dimension values* or if you have to set up separate alarms *for each dimension value*. I'm hoping for a way to do the former because I don't want to have to dynamically create and destroy CW alarms.

Is it possible to have one CloudWatch alarm that covers all dimensions for a custom metric?